Functional variants of Dirac delta function
in one of my assignments i was asked to list down three different functional variants of Dirac delta function. all i know about dirac delta function is that it represents a pulse with very huge amplitude and with an infinitesimally small width,such that the integral of it over the entire number line is 1. one of the functional variant is by defining it as a derivative of heaviside step function, at zero the huge spike in value can be though of the function having a very huge slope. what could be other possible variants of Dirac-delta?

Do you believe that the purpose of the assignment was for you to ask on SE or to do some research yourself into this?

i did some research myself, i could not get convincing answers anywhere. i could not understand the results i got, the deadline is over anyway iam just curious to learn about this.

you can take a look here for a list of possible functional representations.

You can take any function $f(x)$ which has a peak at $x=0$
with width $\propto\epsilon$, height $\propto\frac{1}{\epsilon}$
and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\ dx=1$.
Then take the limit $\epsilon\to 0$.
Some examples (taken from here) are:
$$\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon^2}}e^{-x^2/2\epsilon^2}$$
$$\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}$$
